# Micro video engine interactions with Image class

Tags: c++, sdl, sprite, game-engine

*[I hope this is appropriate for SO, I thought it was a bit too practical for "programmers" and too technical for "gamedev" but feel free to move if it doesn't fit.]*

Basically I just wanted a quick check on my actual design for a micro video engine that should simply be able to draw images (rendering library is irrelevant) and animated sprites. I am having a hard time wrapping my head around a good design for this task though as I think rendering should be done by my VideoEngine class (hence not in Image) but this leads me to be forced to use `friend` and `extern` which is not good design as I hear. This may be because I have not coded this properly but I think it's more of a design question.

```
// Sprite.h
class Image
{
public:
    Image();
    Image(std::string path);
    ~Image();

    bool IsDisplayable() { return displayed; }
    void LoadImage(std::string path);

    static std::vector<Image*> image_list;
private:
    SDL_Surface*    image_surface;
    bool            displayed;

    friend class    VideoEngine;
};

// VideoEngine.h
extern class Image;

class VideoEngine
{
public:
    VideoEngine();
    VideoEngine(int width, int height);
    ~ VideoEngine();

    void Initialize(int width, int height);
    void RenderImages();
    void ShutdownVE();
private:
    SDL_Surface*    main_display;
    SDL_Rect        main_display_area;
};

// VideoEngine.cpp
void VideoEngine::RenderImages()
{
    std::vector<Image*>::const_iterator ci;
    for(ci = Image::image_list.cbegin(); ci != Image::image_list.cend(); ci++)
    {
        if((*ci) != 0 && (*ci)->IsDisplayable())
        {
            SDL_BlitSurface((*ci)->image_surface, 0, main_display, 0);
            SDL_Flip(main_display);
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, the fact that I need to access `image_surface` inside the `Image` from the `VideoEngine` class forces me to use `friend` and `extern` and doing the other way around (Image having the rendering function) would just force me to use the exact opposite (VideoEngine being friend with Image, which I think is ugly).

**TLDR:** Is this kind of double-relationship solvable by any clean way ? One thing I think could be doable but would incur more checking on resources is notifying VideoEngine in some way each time an image is created and pass it the SDL_Surface pointer to store in a list. Would this be better design ?

Comment: And before anyone mentions it: I do know that my Image class is extremely simplistic (no care given to source rect, alpha or even its position) but I want to get the overall design done before working on specifics. If I can draw an image, then drawing it in a specific spot is just a matter of adding a few parameters to function calls and a few members in the class.

Comment: Why don't you want to make the image surface public?

Comment: Why don't you have a getter for `surface` ?

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me that you can't really do anything with your Image other than load it.  Maybe you should have some sort of drawing context interface.  I.e. so that you could say `image->drawTo(x, y, screen)` for some definition of `screen`?

Since you definitely seem to be using `SDL_Surface`s as your lowest level primitive, it might make sense to have a `void Image::drawTo(..., SDL_Surface* )` method.  This would give you some small degree of encapsulation, at least.

Also, having a static or global `vector` of `Images` anywhere strikes me as a problem waiting to happen.  Particularly if that `vector` or its contents are ever subject to change after initial loading.